# Initializing array of structs in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've initialized an array of structs with three items and [it is showing 2](https://ideone.com/L1FWqV) for me !!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct record {
    int value;
    char *name;
} record;

int main (void) {
    record list[] = { (1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three") };
    int n = sizeof(list) / sizeof(record);

    printf("list's length: %i \n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

What is happening here? Am I getting crazy?

Comment: Are there any errors or is it just a silent fail?

Comment: You should not even be able to run that code. It will give you errors since you did not initialize `record list[]` properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change initialization to:

```
record list[] = { {1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"} };
/*                ^        ^  ^        ^  ^          ^  */
```

Your initialization with `(...)` leaves effect similar to `{"one", "two", "three"}` and creates a struct array with elements `{ {(int)"one", "two"}, {(int)"three", (char *)0} }`

[comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in C evaluates the expressions from left to right and discard all except the last. This is the reason why `1`, `2` and `3` are discarded.

Comment: Could you explain why does `sizeof(list)` returns 16 when initialized the wrong way?

Comment: Thank you.. now I'm seeing the issue

Comment: I'm glad if the answer helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not initializing  `list` properly. **Putting initializing elements in `()` will let the compiler to treat `,` as [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) instead of separator**.

Your compiler should give these warnings

```
[Warning] left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
[Warning] missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
[Warning] (near initialization for 'list[0]') [-Wmissing-braces]
[Warning] initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
[Warning] (near initialization for 'list[0].value') [enabled by default]
[Warning] left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
[Warning] left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
[Warning] initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
[Warning] (near initialization for 'list[1].value') [enabled by default]
[Warning] missing initializer for field 'name' of 'record' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
```

Initialization should be done as

```
 record list[] = { {1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"} };
```

Comment: Thank you... I didn't see this warnings... ideone compiled it as normal code